# How do I disable global gnome shortcuts in gnome-terminal?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Bash has a [myriad of useful shortcuts](http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html). For instance <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, which moves the cursor back one word. Only I have assigned this particular combination and a few other shortcuts to do things in gnome. The trouble is, i've gotten used to it. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> opens my browser and I'd like for it to stay that way, except when I work in gnome terminal.

Hence my question: How do I disable global shortcuts, (like the one to open my browser) and enable bash's own shortcuts, exclusively when working in gnome-terminal? Is there a way to tell gnome that the active/focused application's shortcuts take precedence over global shortcuts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a new feature or not but there is an option:

- go to edit - keyboard preferences - unckeck "Enable menu access keys (Such as Alt+F to open the File menu)"

Comment: That would disable them everywhere. I want to selectively disable them only when working in gnome-terminal.

Comment: @con-f-use tibike's way only affects the gnome-terminal, it's an option in gnome-terminal, but not system wide. I got the same issue, his solution works.

Comment: @con-f-use This is the answer. You should uncheck the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, apart from projecting complicated things monitoring focused/unfocused window, and changing shortcuts correspondingly.

So the advice is to avoid shortcut collisions.

Comment: I feared that much. That's pretty unsatisfactory and surely a feature to be implemented. I'll leave the question open for a while. Maybe someone has a hack for that.